# Android battery level intent crashes with java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'p'

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a really strange crash quite hard to reproduce as my code works 99,999999% of the time.
I'm on Android API 25. I read the battery level thanks to the Battery changed intents:

```
class BatteryService {
    val batteryLevelPercent = Observable.using(
        {
            val rxObserver = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()

            val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(arg0: Context, intent: Intent) {
                    val level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
                    rxObserver.onNext(level)
                    Timber.i("battery level = $level")
                }
            }

            context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))

            receiver to rxObserver
        },
        { (_, observer) -> observer },
        { (receiver, _) ->
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    ).replay(1)
        .refCount()
```

Easy, but in the rare cases I got crashes the battery was very low, about 0 to 1%. I got this exception:

```
io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$Array2Func.apply Functions.java, line 529
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'p'
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion Formatter.java:2730
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init> Formatter.java:2759
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init> Formatter.java:2591
java.util.Formatter.parse Formatter.java:2524
java.util.Formatter.format Formatter.java:2472
java.util.Formatter.format Formatter.java:2426
java.lang.String.format String.java:2626
com.telecomdesign.amelia.settings.menu.advanced.systemUpdate.SystemUpdateViewModel$$special$$inlined$combineLatest$1.apply Observables.kt:252
io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$Array2Func.apply Functions.java:529
io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$Array2Func.apply Functions.java:516
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.drain ObservableCombineLatest.java:197
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.innerNext ObservableCombineLatest.java:237
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$CombinerObserver.onNext ObservableCombineLatest.java:306
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.drain ObservableCombineLatest.java:208
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.innerNext ObservableCombineLatest.java:237
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCombineLatest$CombinerObserver.onNext ObservableCombineLatest.java:306
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext ObservableMap.java:62
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRefCount$RefCountObserver.onNext ObservableRefCount.java:208
io.reactivex.internal.util.NotificationLite.accept NotificationLite.java:246
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableReplay$BoundedReplayBuffer.replay ObservableReplay.java:698
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableReplay$ReplayObserver.replay ObservableReplay.java:401
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableReplay$ReplayObserver.onNext ObservableReplay.java:366
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUsing$UsingObserver.onNext ObservableUsing.java:104
io.reactivex.internal.util.NotificationLite.accept NotificationLite.java:246
io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject$BehaviorDisposable.test BehaviorSubject.java:569
io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject$BehaviorDisposable.emitNext BehaviorSubject.java:564
io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext BehaviorSubject.java:268
com.mypackage.BatteryServiceDefault$batteryLevelPercent$1$receiver$1.onReceive BatteryService.kt:29
```

The "BatteryService.kt:29" line is `rxObserver.onNext(level)`. I suppose the crash does not come from RX but from the intent as it has certainly be inlined by the compiler. My theory is that the intent extra level is not properly formatted but contains a `p` instead of an integer that it can't convert string to int.

Did someone already report that ? Might it be an android bug in the battery level border cases ?
Thanks in advance if you have any clue.

Comment: Try logging `level` before calling `rxObserver.onNext` and see what comes out, perhaps?

Comment: Yes thank you Petter, I'll do something like that and i'll add a try catch just in case. I'll come back to you if I successfully log something.

Comment: Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77988364/9133569